# Android: How to create a grid layout with specific columns and rows that fill all the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to create a grid layout with a specific number of columns and rows but I haven't found the solution. The grid has 2 columns and 4 rows and this grid needs to fill all the screen. Also each of the inner boxes have a text and an image. This is how it should look:

[image]

Comment: share what you have done so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I had to use nested linear and relative layouts.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/categorias_table">

<!--ROW-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/categoria1_box"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoria_image_1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_alerts"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/categoria1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/categoria_image_1"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/categoria2_box"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoria_image_2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_alerts"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/categoria2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/categoria_image_2"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<!--END ROW-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of creating custom GridLayout: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76&aaid=100

Just improve some changes in layouts and you have what you want.